# Subclassing keras.model to create a custom autoregressive LSTM model with multi-column input

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I'm trying to create a model to forecast energy grid load (net electricity consumed by the grid) based on weather data. In production, we won't have load data to do a standard batch prediction. We're trying an autoregressive approach so that we can feed it the last reported load reading and the next 24 hours of forecasted weather data to produce a 24 hour prediction of load.

I'm working from [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#advanced_autoregressive_model), which recommends subclassing the model class to make a step by step prediction. I believe the model.fit documentation also recommends subclassing.

The above tutorial creates a subclass of keras.model called Feedback and overwrites the model.call() method, which is called during training and prediction.

```
def call(self, inputs, training=None):
  # Use a TensorArray to capture dynamically unrolled outputs.
  predictions = []
  # Initialize the LSTM state.
  prediction, state = self.warmup(inputs)

  # Insert the first prediction.
  predictions.append(prediction)

  # Run the rest of the prediction steps.
  for n in range(1, self.out_steps):
    # Use the last prediction as input.
    x = prediction
    # Execute one lstm step.
    x, state = self.lstm_cell(x, states=state,
                              training=training)
    # Convert the lstm output to a prediction.
    prediction = self.dense(x)
    # Add the prediction to the output.
    predictions.append(prediction)

  # predictions.shape => (time, batch, features)
  predictions = tf.stack(predictions)
  # predictions.shape => (batch, time, features)
  predictions = tf.transpose(predictions, [1, 0, 2])
  return predictions
```

When calling fit(), I pass in datasets for training and validation. The datasets made via keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array().

```
history = model.fit(dataset_train, epochs=epochs,
                    validation_data=dataset_val,
                    callbacks=[es_callback, modelckpt_callback])
```

My data shapes are hourly time series data, 11 columns of weather data and 1 column of targets. I'm using a window size of two hours.

My issue is that it seems as though the prediction calls in the for loop are only using previous predictions as input. I don't understand how they could be accessing the training or validation datasets.

I tried looking around in the Pycharm debugger for a way to access the datasets, but didn't find anything. I also tried looking for people doing similar subclassing, but this tutorial is the best I could find.

If a running example is needed, that tutorial goes through dataset creation and subclass implementation. My hope is that someone could explain how to properly subclass keras.model (in a similar fashion to that tutorial) to take multiple-column input, and do autoregressive predictions. The overwriting of the call() method is where I'm most confused.

Answer (score 0):

```
prediction, state = self.warmup(inputs)
```

Takes the entire input and produce a single initial prediction. This is then used to predict the next time steps.
Note that if the num_features is not equal to the target shape you would need an down/upsampling layer at the end.

My edited version:

```
class FeedBack(tf.keras.Model):
def __init__(self, units, out_steps, num_features, num_outputs):
    super().__init__()
    self.out_steps = out_steps
    self.units = units
    self.lstm_cell = tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(units)
    # Also wrap the LSTMCell in an RNN to simplify the `warmup` method.
    self.lstm_rnn = tf.keras.layers.RNN(self.lstm_cell, return_state=True)
    self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_features)
    self.output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_outputs)

def warmup(self, inputs):
    # inputs.shape => (batch, time, features)
    # x.shape => (batch, lstm_units)
    x, *state = self.lstm_rnn(inputs)

    # predictions.shape => (batch, features)
    prediction = self.dense(x)
    return prediction, state

def call(self, inputs, training=None):
    # Use a TensorArray to capture dynamically unrolled outputs.
    predictions = []
    # Initialize the LSTM state.
    prediction, state = self.warmup(inputs)

    # Insert the first prediction.
    predictions.append(prediction)

    # Run the rest of the prediction steps.
    for n in range(1, self.out_steps):
        # Use the last prediction as input.
        x = prediction
        # Execute one lstm step.
        x, state = self.lstm_cell(x, states=state,
                                training=training)
        # Convert the lstm output to a prediction.
        prediction = self.dense(x)
        # Add the prediction to the output.
        predictions.append(prediction)

    # predictions.shape => (time, batch, features)
    predictions = tf.stack(predictions)
    # predictions.shape => (batch, time, features)
    predictions = tf.transpose(predictions, [1, 0, 2])
    predictions = self.output_layer(predictions)
    return predictions
```